# ASP.NET Core3.1 webapi deployment TTFB > 1 minute

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

We have an app deployed on IIS. We use most of the configuration by defaut(recycling period, idle-timeout, etc.).

But after new deployment (or recycling), the TTFB would take one more minute to warm-up.

And I tested deployed the same app (webapi and site) on my local IIS, it took 8 secs for a full warmup.

What makes this big difference on latency?

Could someone shed any lights? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to profile your application on the system which runs slowly?

Comment: Use a performance profilder to see what takes so long in the initialization, and then you can perform some optimization.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Any advice on the profiling tools for this scenario? any tools for installing on the server?